# Auto printing 3 different reports in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am looking to print 3 different reports from pressing 1 command button.

When they press print, I want the reports to just print, I do not want a printer prompt for them to confirm the print, I simply want it to print once the command button is pressed

So far I have this:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptLearning", acViewPreview, "", "", acNormal
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptNeutral", acViewPreview, "", "", acNormal
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptPositive", acViewPreview, "", "", acNormal
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdPrint
```

This shows the printer prompt which I don't want.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `acViewNormal` instead of `acViewPreview` to print directly.

So all you need is

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptLearning", acViewNormal
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptNeutral", acViewNormal
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptPositive", acViewNormal
```

(`acViewNormal` is the default, so if you want you can leave even that out.)

Comment: Thank you Andre - I tried this but I still get the normal print prompt, I have to click OK then it will print.